# Отступы в firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

```
<div style="color: red">test</div>
<div style="color: blue; margin-top: 3px;">test</div>
```

Firefox будто вместо 3px подставляет свои 5px. Как исправить?

Comment: скорее всего это у вас где-то ошибка, покажите больше кода - такой короткий код работает правильно

Comment: замечал такое, только на 1px больше, в chrome все точно... впринципе тоже интересен этот вопрос.

Comment: Второй раз удаляю метку bad-browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте:

```
line-height: 1px;
```

В этом плане Mozilla и IE как как-будто сговорились.

Answer (score 2):

А Вы уверены в этом?

Может `!important` поможет?

```
<div style="color: blue; margin-top: 3px!important;">test</div>
```

Comment: @vesel4ak, не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

А вы что хотите получить? Не совсем понятно. В firefox расстояние между дивами ровно 3px

Comment: Может быть в последней версии и ровно. Но в предпоследней есть лаги. То все увеличивается, пока height не задашь, а если и задашь, то текст опускается на 2 пикселя ниже. Или пропишешь маргин в 3 пикселя, а файрфокс свои +2 пикселя еще сунет.

Comment: Запилите на jsfiddle, пожалуйста. Или просто вам нужно что-то другое. Понять сложно в чем проблема. Margin-top ведет себя так как и должен вести и в ранних версиях

Answer (score 1):

Для текста задавайте свойство `line-height` - отступ междустрочный будет везде одинаковым.
Также если это div блоки, обнулите `padding`, может помочь.